# Trouble deleting customer record in django using Bootstrap5 Modal/Jquery

Tags: jquery, django, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to delete a customer record when clicking on the modal popup delete button in bootstrap 5 but when I click on 'Yes, I want to delete' , nothing happens and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. i've checked some of the other queries around this topic but still unable to get it to work. Below is what I have so far. Really appreciate any help on this!

Customer record card with button

```
<div class="p-3 text-primary-emphasis bg-primary-subtle border border-primary-subtle rounded-3">
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
       <strong>{{ customer_record.first_name }}
        {{ customer_record.last_name }}</strong>
    </div>

    <div class="card-body">

        <p class="card-text">
        <strong>Email: </strong> {{ customer_record.email }}
        </p>

        <p class="card-text">
        <strong>Phone:  </strong> {{ customer_record.phone }}
        </p>

        <p class="card-text">
        <strong>Address: </strong> {{ customer_record.address }}
        </p>

        <p class="card-text">
        <strong>City: </strong> {{ customer_record.city }}
        </p>

        <p class="card-text">
        <strong>Postcode: </strong> {{ customer_record.postcode }}
        </p>

        <p class="card-text">
        <strong>Created At: </strong>  {{ customer_record.created_at }}
        </p>

        <p class="card-text">
        <strong>Company: </strong> {{ company_info.name }}
        </p>

        <p class="card-text">
        <strong>ID: </strong> {{ customer_record.id }}
        </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br/><br/>


<a href="{% url 'update_customer' customer_record.id %}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Update Customer Information</a>

<a href="{% url 'delete_record' customer_record.id %}"  class="btn btn-danger btn-sm deleteCustomer" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#deleteCustomer{{customer_record.id}}">Delete Customer</a>
```

Delete customer modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="deleteCustomer{{ customer_record.id }}" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="deleteCustomerLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="deleteCustomerLabel">Delete Customer</h1>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Are you sure you want to delete <strong>{{customer_record.first_name}} {{customer_record.last_name}}</strong>? This action cannot be undone. 
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
       <form action="{% url 'delete_record' customer_record.id %}" id="deleteCustomerForm" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %} 
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="deleteCustomerButton{{customer_record.id}}" type="submit">Yes, I want to delete</button>
       </form>    
      <button type="button" id ="cancelDelete" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">No</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

jquery

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#deleteCustomerButton').on('click', function() {
      var customer_record = {
    id: {{ customer_record.id }}
      };
      $('#deleteCustomerForm').submit(function(event) {
        $('#deleteCustomer'+ customer_record.id).remove();
    });
  });
  });
</script>
```

So far I am able to click on the delete button and get the pop up with the delete confirmation but when i click on 'Yes I want to delete', nothing happens. Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Have you checked your network tab? Is there a request that is being sent that is not properly handled, or is it not even sending a request?

Comment: @LajosArpad Nothing happening under the network tab at all. Under the Elements tabs when I click on the delete button I'm getting a jquery error: 
Uncaught ReferenceError: customer_record is not defined. 

When I remove the Jquery script error disapears so I know there's something to be looked at there. II've been looking for days at how to remove the customer record when confirming the delete. Really stuck.

Comment: You prevent the form to submit, so the view is never triggered with a request.

Comment: So, is this the line where you get the error? `$('#deleteCustomer', customer_record.id).remove();`

Comment: @WillemVOsupportsmodstrike How am I preventing the form to submit? Can you expand please.

Comment: @LajosArpad I think so, it must be. But I reference cusotmer_record.id in my Django code as being the id of the record, so not sure how it's not defined.

Comment: The ID's in your HTML are mess. You have there `id="deleteCustomer{{ customer_record.id }}"` and `id="#deleteCustomer{{customer_record.id}}"`. I'd highly recommend to not use `#` in there. Make the IDs different enough to avoid confusion. Also the attribute `href` does not belong in the `<button>` tag, it doesnt do anything there. Plus the jQuery should be probably `$('#deleteCustomer' + customer_record.id)` instead of `$('#deleteCustomer', customer_record.id)` (plus vs comma).

Comment: `event.preventDefault();`...

Comment: @WillemVOsupportsmodstrike Yup, so i removed that and did the following:

<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
  $('.btn-danger').on('click', function() {
    $('form').submit() 
      $('#deleteCustomer', customer_record.id).remove();
    }
  )
  });

</script>

Now the modal doesnt pop up when clicking delete at all. I just want the modal to act as the delete button instead of the original bootstrap one...

Comment: @klauscode: yes, in that case you need to make an AJAX request, just preventing the form to submit will not help.

Comment: @klauscode then the problem starts to get clear. You have a server-side `{{ customer_record.id }}` that you render for the client-side, but it is never passed to a JS variable.

Comment: @LajosArpad , makes sense, thank you. Have updated my code, please see comment below, really appreciate the guidance.

Comment: @WillemVOsupportsmodstrike , i've updated my jQuery now, thanks for the tips. There are no console errors but nothing happens when clicking delete still - anything you can see in my script thats obviously wrong? I store the variable and then try to submit the form and remove the record... was hoping this would be enough. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you expect a server-side resource to be present at your client-side, but you need to understand that these are often very different computers, so the resources are not transform automatically and you need to transform them yourself, like:

```
<script>
var customer_record = {
    id: {{ customer_record.id }}
};
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I've updated my code to reflect the suggestions. now I'm not getting any errors in the console but still nothing happens at all when I click on delete; the modal does pop up, but no deletion happens. 

Could you glance at my jquery script and let me know if there's any glaring issues please? Appreciate the help so far.

Comment: @klauscode you will need to debug this. You have this line: `$('#deleteCustomer'+ customer_record.id).remove();`. Please prepend a new line exactly before this one that will be `debugger;`. That will make sure that a debugger jumps there when your event runs. You can watch values and I would be particularly interested in the result of `'#deleteCustomer'+ customer_record.id` and whether that matches the selector you are interested about.

Comment: It works! So turns out I needed to change the input type of my modal 'delete' button to <input> with the type submit and it worked. No Jquery, no JS needed since I'm using old school form method to POST the request. Thanks for your help !